# PHP forward slash in json post request

Tags: php, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, lumen

I have fcm server.Build in Laravel lumen.

Server url: `https://firenoti.000webhostapp.com/fcmserver/public/api/noti`

Post request: `title=Hi&token=f12S4al_8dg:APA91bFuNy4SrMOH8AiK0M_AGd8SUIraegqYEPgffdBY6AujN6b84ALtM22W9mAocuBq5bf83mHqOPPP1T-OSW0rAVMUVIOQkDxEd9l-MoQ3kaNrv4d4Q5pOsl5qKahwx_55FZ-Gf9gV&body=Hello`

I use HttpRequester for post request.
This is my server code:

```
public function getData(Request $request)
 {

$firebase_url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$api_key  =  ”api_key”;

if ($request->has('token')  &&  $request->has('token')  &&  $request->has('token')) {

  $token = $request->get('token');
  $title = $request->get('title');
  $body = $request->get('body');

    if($token == "ALL"){
        $token = "/topics/all";
      }

  $fields = ['to' => $token,'data'=> array('title' => $title, 'body' => $body)];
  $headers = ['Content-type : application/json; charset=utf-8"',"Authorization:key = ".$api_key];

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $firebase_url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  $result_array = json_decode($result,true);

  if ($result_array['success'] == 1) {

    $status = "OK";
    $res_message = "Notification send successfuly";

  }else{

    $status = "ERROR";
    $res_message = "Notification sending fail";

  }
  return response()->json(["status" => $status,"message"=>$res_message]);

}else{

  return response()->json(["status" => 'ERROR',"message"=>'Invalid request format']);

    }
}
```

`

When I send a request with user token everything work fine. [image]

But when I send post request with token=ALL I get error
[image]

I think problem is here

```
if($token == "ALL"){
    $token = "/topics/all";
}
```

How to fix that?

Comment: did you used any JWT ? if you using JWT then you have to used other variable instead using token. token variable used for verification of user.

Comment: noo. i don't use any jwt

Comment: did you add post route ??

Comment: yes.post with user token work correctly. look images

Comment: $fields = ['to' => $token,'data'=> array('title' => $title, 'body' => $body)];
problem is here.  you cant send to all you have to use all the token for send notification for every user .

Comment: From  Firebase docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }
}

in our condition foo-bar=all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150930/discussion-between-beginner-and-shashikant).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150991/discussion-between-beginner-and-shashikant-chauhan).

Answer (score 0):

> I think problem is here

That isn't the problem. That is the solution.

The code says "If the token is *ALL* then use */topics/all* instead".

When you are making the request manually you are sending *ALL* instead of */topics/all*.